# find the continuous function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

[image]

Well the "weird" property is continuity and we can see that the function is not injective. Well actually I think I am missing something.
It seems like $f(x) = \frac{x}{x} = 1$ is good ? For example :
 $$f(4 + 5) = f(9) = 1 = f(4) \cdot f(5) = 1\cdot 1$$

Comment: Anything of the form $a^x$ will work (well, if $a>0$, at least)....your example just corresponds to $a=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exponential function.
$f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)$ implies $f(0)=1$.

$f(1)f(-1)=f(0)=1$ implies $f(-1)=f(1)^{-1}$.

Then for any integer, $f(n)=f(1)^n$ and $f(1/n)=f(1)^{1/n}$. Therefore, for all rational $p$, $f(p)=f(1)^p$.

By continuity, $f(x)=f(1)^x$.

Comment: A detail: $f(x+0) = f(x)f(0)$ implies $f(0)=1$ only at some $x$ where $f(x)\ne 0$. Such an $x$ exists as $f$ isn't identically $0$, but $x$ can't be arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.